# Hooking an App made on MSVC++ with __fastcall enabled from an injected Delphi dll

Tags: visual-studio-2010, delphi, assembly, hook, delphi-2010

I am trying to hook a function within a application compiled with microsoft visual studio 2010, with __fastcall enabled from a delphi 2010 dll, but I am not to skilled to figure out how to detour the following problem:

The C++ function is:

```
     void __fastcall function(int arg1; char* arg2);
```

I was trying something like that (using uallHook):

```
    var FTextMessage : procedure(Modo: integer; Msg: pchar); register;
    procedure onTextMessage(Modo: integer; Msg: pchar); register;
    begin
      ShowMessage(inttostr(Modo) + ' - ' + string(Msg));
      FTextMessage(Modo, Msg);
    end;
    begin
    HookCode(Ptr($574210), @onTextMessage, @FTextMessage);
    end.
```

This is leading to debugs/crashes.

So, I found that:

> "Microsoft or GCC[4] __fastcall[5] convention (aka __msfastcall) passes the first two arguments (evaluated left to right) that fit into ECX and EDX. Remaining arguments are pushed onto the stack from right to left."
>
> Borland fastcall
>   Evaluating arguments from left to right, it passes three arguments via EAX, EDX, ECX. Remaining arguments are pushed onto the stack, also left to right.[6]
>   It is the default calling convention of the 32 bit compiler of Embarcadero Delphi, where >it is known as register.

Taken from: 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions

This is the problem, borland fastcall and microsoft __fastcall are different.

So I'm thinking that I will need to use a piece of assembly code inside the Hook function to align registers or something, but I'm not able to figure this yet.

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit1:
David Heffernan Answer works partially. (it only works until showmessage)

```
     var FTextMessage : procedure(Modo: integer;Msg: PAnsiChar); register;

     procedure onTextMessage(Modo: integer;Msg: PAnsiChar); register;
     begin
       ShowMessage(inttostr(Modo) + ' - ' + string(Msg));
       asm
         MOV ECX,Modo
         MOV EDX,Msg
         JMP FTextMessage
       end;  // I got a crash trying or without trying to restore the registers before executing the JMP FTextMessage
     //  FTextMessage(Modo,Msg); // < Also this method doesnt work either, if I call the Original function from here (without executing asm code above) i got a crash too. (this is what i was meaning with "to correct the registers")
     end;

     procedure onTextMessageWrapper(Modo: Integer;Msg: PAnsiChar); register;
     asm
       MOV EDX,ECX  // < Moving ECX to EDX, I'm able to Access Modo and Msg correctly in onTextMessage procedure.
       JMP onTextMessage
     end;

     begin
       HookCode(Ptr($574210), @onTextMessageWrapper, @FTextMessage);
     end.
```

Comment: You didn't read David's answer well enough. He clearly mentions moving `ECX` to `EAX`, but your edit shows code moving to `EDX` instead.

Comment: Thats because moving ECX to EAX didn't worked, the values passed to Modo and Msg wasn't right.

Comment: @renato If the function you are hooking really is `__fastcall`, then `MOV ECX,EAX` is correct. Have you entertained the possibility that this function is not `__fastcall`?

Comment: Look at onTextMessage code in assembler window. Since it calls external API like ShowMessage - it probably allocates stack frame tro save registers into tempporary variables. And your JMP then ruines this.
Hooking function should ONLY EVER contain few FINELY CONTROLLED assembler opcodes. All the rest like ShowMessage - that can engage compiler automagics - should be offloaded to tightly isolated external functions!  You need ShowMessage ? make a separate procedure and call it using only PURE ASSEMBLER !

Comment: Since it works with `EDX` I guess he is using object methods instead of flat functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C++ function is passing parameters in `ECX` and `EDX`. So you just need to copy them to the registers that Delphi is expecting: `EAX` and `EDX` respectively. Since the second parameter is already in the right register all you need is this:

```
procedure onTextMessage(Modo: Integer; Msg: PAnsiChar); register;
begin
  ...
end;

procedure onTextMessageWrapper(Modo: Integer; Msg: PAnsiChar); register;
asm
  MOV EAX,ECX
  JMP onTextMessage
end;
```

I've done this in two functions so that I can write a pure `asm` only function that does the register swapping. We want pure `asm` to avoid all preamble. So, `onTextMessageWrapper` is your hook function.

Note also that since you are using a Unicode Delphi, you will want `PAnsiChar` to match up with `char*`.

The best reference I know for calling conventions is by [Agner Fog](http://www.agner.org/optimize/calling_conventions.pdf). You'll find all the gory details there. One important point is that, on Windows x86, the EAX, ECX and EDX registers are volatile, or scratch registers. Which means that callees can modify those registers without having to restore them. Which is why I modify EAX above and do not bother to put it back.

Comment: just a side question, we should not do some assembling on onTextMessage right before calling the original function ( FTextMessage(Modo, Msg); ), to correct the registers for original application or something?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. What I have here should be all you need.

Comment: Moving ECX to EAX doesnt Work :(

Comment: Why not? My test was fine. From what you've posted in the question, you are doing all sorts of weird things. How can I tell what you've done.

Comment: @renato If the string is arriving in ECX, then it cannot be the second parameter of a `__fastcall` function.

Comment: @David - look at his second code, i guess he polluted the stack with temporary variables by calling ShowMessage.
Also - does HookCode autpomatically recovering original function called ? Won't JMP send him to the hook itself like infinite loop ? sorry, i only hooked others code in DOS times :-)

Comment: The stack parameters from the pic are filled just before entering the hooked function(without modifications by the dll), right now I am very confused, I need some time to figure out what i'm telling wrong to you guys. I'm very sorry

Comment: @renato - the nsee the assembler code exactly before the function call. It is usually very clear where it takes parameters and where it puts it to store. PS. read that Wikipedia article, rather funny, it looks like MS C++ does not use registers for class methods: except for this==ECX, all other parameters go to stack

Comment: @Arioch'The Please see this pic: http://i45.tinypic.com/2s64kk1.png seems that the text string is passed via ecx and the Modo variable is in eax

Comment: That's not `__fastcall` then is it?

Comment: Actually - where did you got function declaration from ??? to me it looks `varargs` like `printf` - 1st argument passed via ECX, then unknown number of arguments (here - the only one) passed on stack, after the call stack is cleaned by caller who knows how many arguments it pushed (ADD  ESP, 4).  There should be other places where this functio nis caleld from - check them all and compare.

Comment: I got from this post http://tpforums.org/forum/thread-11638.html , but this is from an old program version where the coders didn't use __fastcall, the function is still 2 params.

Comment: All this is a long way from the question you asked. You asked how to adapt `__fastcall` to `register`. I have answered the question you asked. I'm in no position to reverse engineer whatever your actual problem is.

Answer (score -1):

Another try is to change this function signature as below

From: procedure onTextMessageWrapper(Modo: Integer; Msg: PAnsiChar); register;
To: procedure onTextMessageWrapper; register;