# How to hook Delphi function using C++

Tags: c++, delphi, hook

I am trying to hook a user-defined function of a program written in Delphi using C++ and Detours library. (DLL Injection)

However, I can't hook it because Delphi's and C++'s function calling conventions don't match.

Delphi uses the fastcall function calling convention, and C++ also provides a fastcall function calling convention.

However, Delphi's fastcall stores its arguments sequentially on EAX, EDX, ECX, and the stack, whereas C++'s fastcall stores its arguments sequentially on ECX, EDX, and stack. (This is because there is no standard for fastcall.)

Due to these differences, I have no way to get the arguments stored in EAX.

How can I solve this problem?

*(This article has been translated by Google Translate.)*

---

< dllmain.cpp >

```
#include "pch.h"

typedef void(__fastcall* ORGFP)(char); //Prototype of function to hook (reverse engineering)
ORGFP originFunc1 = (ORGFP)((DWORD)GetModuleHandle(NULL) + 0x2B2F20); //Image base of target process + offset of function to hook
ORGFP originFunc2 = (ORGFP)((DWORD)GetModuleHandle(NULL) + 0x2B2A20);

DWORD WriteLog(LPCTSTR lpszFormat, ...) {
    TCHAR szLog[512];
    DWORD dwCharsWritten;

    va_list args;
    va_start(args, lpszFormat);
    _vstprintf_s(szLog, 512, lpszFormat, args);
    va_end(args);

    WriteConsole(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), szLog, _tcslen(szLog), &dwCharsWritten, NULL);

    return dwCharsWritten;
}

void __fastcall DetourFunc1(char on) {
    WriteLog(TEXT("Function called : BlockInternet(%d)\n"), on);
    return originFunc1(on);
}

void __fastcall DetourFunc2(char on) {
    WriteLog(TEXT("Function called : BlockInputDevices(%d)\n"), on);
    return originFunc2(on);
}

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule, DWORD ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID lpReserved) {
    if (DetourIsHelperProcess())
        return TRUE;

    switch (ul_reason_for_call) {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        AllocConsole();
        DetourRestoreAfterWith();
        DetourTransactionBegin();
        DetourUpdateThread(GetCurrentThread());
        DetourAttach(&(PVOID&)originFunc1, DetourFunc1);
        DetourAttach(&(PVOID&)originFunc2, DetourFunc2);
        DetourTransactionCommit();
        break;
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        FreeConsole();
        DetourTransactionBegin();
        DetourUpdateThread(GetCurrentThread());
        DetourDetach(&(PVOID&)originFunc1, DetourFunc1);
        DetourDetach(&(PVOID&)originFunc2, DetourFunc2);
        DetourTransactionCommit();
        break;
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

< pch.cpp >

```
#include "pch.h"
```

< pch.h >

```
#ifndef PCH_H
#define PCH_H

#include "framework.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <detours.h>

#endif
```

< framework.h >

```
#pragma once

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <windows.h>
```

Comment: Some assembly required.

Comment: @500 - Internal Server Error // Can you please explain exactly what assembly you need?

Comment: You need to write the code to prepare the parameters for the call in assembly. You can't get the compiler to do it. So you have to take on the job of the compiler. That's if you are restricted to using C++ code. What you could instead do is use a small Delphi DLL to handle the `register` call for you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hooking an App made on MSVC++ with \_\_fastcall enabled from an injected Delphi dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13703303/hooking-an-app-made-on-msvc-with-fastcall-enabled-from-an-injected-delphi-dl)

Comment: @Remko // This is not exactly what I was looking for, but it helped a lot. thank you!

Comment: C++Builder is the only C++ compiler that natively supports Delphi's `register` (fastcall) calling convention, where `__fastcall` is for Delphi's fastcall, and there is a separate `__msfastcall` for Microsoft's flavor of fastcall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem using `__declspec(naked)`! Thanks to everyone who helped me!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <detours.h>
using namespace std;

__declspec(naked) void __fastcall originFunction(char arg) {
    __asm {
        push ebp
        mov ebp, esp
        sub esp, __LOCAL_SIZE
    }
    __asm {
        mov byte ptr [arg], al
    }
    cout << (int)arg << endl;
    __asm {
        mov esp, ebp
        pop ebp
        ret
    }
}

typedef void(__fastcall* FP)(char);
FP originFunctionPointer = originFunction;

__declspec(naked) void __fastcall detourFunction(char arg) {
    __asm {
        push ebp
        mov ebp, esp
        sub esp, __LOCAL_SIZE
    }
    __asm {
        mov byte ptr [arg], al
    }
    cout << (int)arg << endl;
    arg = 0;
    __asm {
        mov al, byte ptr [arg]
        call dword ptr [originFunctionPointer]
    }
    __asm {
        mov esp, ebp
        pop ebp
        ret
    }
}

int main() {
    DetourRestoreAfterWith();
    DetourTransactionBegin();
    DetourUpdateThread(GetCurrentThread());
    DetourAttach(&(PVOID&)originFunctionPointer, detourFunction);
    DetourTransactionCommit();

    __asm {
        mov al, 1h
        call dword ptr [originFunction]
    }

    DetourTransactionBegin();
    DetourUpdateThread(GetCurrentThread());
    DetourDetach(&(PVOID&)originFunctionPointer, detourFunction);
    DetourTransactionCommit();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As per wikipedia:

> Borland register
> Evaluating arguments from left to right, it passes three arguments via EAX, EDX, ECX. Remaining arguments are pushed onto the stack, also left to right.[12] It is the default calling convention of the 32-bit compiler of Delphi, where it is known as register. This calling convention is also used by Embarcadero's C++Builder, where it is called __fastcall.[13] In this compiler, Microsoft's fastcall can be used as __msfastcall.[14]

> GCC and Clang can be made to use a similar calling convention by using __stdcall with the regparm function attribute or the -mregparm=3 switch. (The stack order is inverted.) It is also possible to produce a caller clean-up variant using cdecl or extend this to also use SSE registers.[15] A cdecl-based version is used by the Linux kernel on i386 since version 2.6.20 (released February 2007).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#Borland_register